# Is the "Magician's Nephew," by C. S. Lewis science fiction?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

Could the "Magician's Nephew," by C. S. Lewis be considered science fiction? It has a lot of the classic trademarks of science fiction.

Comment: "It has a lot of the classic trademarks of science fiction." - such as what? Could you give some examples? Narnia seems like straightforward fantasy to me.

Comment: Such as being transported to other worlds or parallel universes. Which I think could count as both fantasy and science fiction.

Answer (score 6):

This is why I don't like the distinction between science fiction and fantasy.  To answer your question, *The Magician's Nephew* is clearly *speculative* fiction, but whether it is *science* fiction is going to depend more on your definition of sci-fi than on the book itself.  I would probably call it [science fantasy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Science_fantasy).

The book involves the scientific concept of parallel universes, and the rings that transport the characters between worlds are explicitly the product of science, not magic (the "magician" in the title is a fraud, or as much of a fraud as you might consider someone who puts on magic shows in real life).  But at the same time, The Chronicles of Narnia is clearly a fantasy series.  Magic runs deep within it, and this magic is not nonexistent in *The Magician's Nephew*.  Aslan does some fairly blatant magic (though I'm not sure C. S. Lewis would call it that) to create Narnia, and while the book does explain where the wardrobe came from, it provides no scientific reasoning about why the wardrobe works as it does.

It is important to remember that science fiction and fantasy are not inherently incompatible.  A story can be both or neither (though the latter is off-topic for this site).  Numerous stories are difficult to classify as sci-fi or fantasy precisely because they are really both at once: *Fullmetal Alchemist*, *A Wrinkle in Time*, most comic book universes, etc.

The good news is that this website covers both genres, so **you can ask questions about Narnia** regardless of whether it is fantasy, sci-fi, or something in between.

Comment: The rings are science and not Alchemy?

Comment: @CreationEdge: It's been years since I read the book, so I could be mistaken on this point, but I do believe they were created by trial and error, which I would characterize as scientific (as opposed to, say, blindly following instructions in some ancient book).

Comment: Alchemy was magical but followed the same stuff. Lots of fantasy does that with magic research. Hard to say!