# How well does Inception fit into the Sci-Fi Genre?

Tags: discussion, scope

I'm trying to work out why Inception fits into the *Sci-Fi genre.* What elements make it 'on-topic' on a site devoted to science fiction and fantasy?

Answer (score 16):

Inception certainly meets the primary criteria that we would normally use to determine suitability for inclusion onto SFF:SE

### Setting

The film is set "[20 minutes into the future](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/TwentyMinutesIntoTheFuture)" in a world where a single large corporation dominates the Energy Sector. Futuristic settings are almost always on topic on SFF:SE

### Conceit

The central conceit of the film is that the main characters use a piece of technology that does not exist, the [PASIV machine](http://inception.wikia.com/wiki/Portable_Automated_Somnacin_IntraVenous_Device), originally designed to for military training but then corrupted to allow information theft. Since the film requires a fundamental suspension of disbelief, it's not only fictional, but *Science*-fictional.

### Marketing and classification

On top of that, the film was marketed as sci-fi (complete with a [viral marketing](http://collider.com/first-poster-from-christopher-nolans-inception-starring-leonardo-dicaprio/) campaign and the [pre-release](http://inception.wikia.com/wiki/Inception:_The_Cobol_Job) of a [range](https://www.nolanfans.com/2010/06/01/dream-share-tactical-employment-procedures-manual/#more-2744) of [prequel materials](http://www.thefirstcity.co.uk/rpg/inception/PASIVinstr.pdf))

[image]

and the cast and crew are pretty open about it being scifi

**Director**

> *Certainly, dreams have been a feature of films in many different ways,
> for years. What “Inception” deals with is a science fiction concept in
> which really only one simple thing has changed, which is that you and
> I are able to experience the same dream at the same time. Once you
> remove the privacy, you’ve created an infinite number of alternate
> universes in which people can meaningfully interact – with validity,
> with weigh, with dramatic consequences.* - <sub><sup>[A Man and His Dream: Christopher Nolan and ‘Inception’](http://artsbeat.blogs.nytimes.com/2010/06/30/a-man-and-his-dream-christopher-nolan-and-inception/?_r=0)</sup></sub>

**Main Actor**

> *"But to answer your question about how one acts in that world or that
> there’s something you need to be aware of or do different, I would say
> absolutely not, and that’s what was exciting about even attempting,
> you know, this was my first science-fiction film. The earliest
> conversations I had with Chris were about how both of us have a hard
> time with science fiction. We have a little bit of an aversion to it
> because it’s hard for us to emotionally invest in worlds that are too
> far detached from what we know."* - <sub><sup>[INTERVIEW: LEONARDO DICAPRIO TALKS INCEPTION AND HOOVER](http://www.mtv.com/news/2764231/interview-leonardo-dicaprio-talks-inception-and-hoover/)</sup></sub>