# Would an objective system for determining whether a work is on-topic or not be useful?

Tags: discussion, scope

There have been numerous debates on what we consider on-topic for this site.

To show some prime and highly debated examples:

- [Are anthropomorphic animals by themselves enough to deem a work fantasy?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5117/are-anthropomorphic-animals-by-themselves-enough-to-deem-a-work-fantasy)
- [Are works that aren't SF per se, but have occasional SFnal elements on-topic? (e.g. spy movies)](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/337/are-works-that-arent-sf-per-se-but-have-occasional-sfnal-elements-on-topic-e)

We even have an FAQ version [What questions are on-topic, and what questions are off-topic?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/350/what-questions-are-on-topic-and-what-questions-are-off-topic) but that has not been updated since 2011.

---

This got me thinking since there has been discussion on how we score our tags. [Does SFF need/have an objective way of scoring tags?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9215/does-sff-need-have-an-objective-way-of-scoring-tags) (although this idea was not well received).

**Would there be someway to bring some objectiveness into how what works we determine on and off topic?** Or is this something that will have to be handled in a discussion format when new works have questions about them?

If not could an **update to the FAQ question** linked need an update? (At least one current discussion  [Policy on questions about which genre or subgenre a given work is in?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9363/policy-on-questions-about-which-genre-or-subgenre-a-given-work-is-in) makes one point on the FAQ debateable.)

**Is any attempt at objective consistency futile?**

Comment: Ah, but then we'd need an objective method to determine what objective methods to use.

Comment: @Valorum HAHA, yes, see my last question/point... Am I new optimism to your old cynicism?

Comment: [This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I_know_it_when_I_see_it) is the only universal way of determining whether a work is on-topic or not. We've been trying for 5 years to come up with something objective; we're unlikely to succeed in the next 5 years. The genres of science fiction and fantasy have never really had clear objective definitions. This is the wrong rabbit hole to go down :-)

Comment: @Randal'Thor I thought it might, but maybe it will at least add to documented discussion on such things?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Yes (as in, it is futile).**

Not simply because it may well be impossible (i'm not 100% sure of that), but **because it's not worth the effort and cost compared to the pay-off**.

- We have VERY VERY few works that are significantly ambiguous as to need to be scored in the first place.
- Most of those works are easily scored by their overall, well-discussed genres (e.g. 007 type films)
- And the few that aren't, can be discussed individually on Meta, at a fraction of the cost and effort to come with complicated scoring generic system applicable to ALL works.

So, we should simply have some broad stroke rules that are **almost** universally applicable but simple; and handle anything that doesn't easily fit them on case by case exception basis on Meta.

Answer (score 5):

When answering questions about topicality, I tend to refer to three key elements;

- Does the film contain substantial elements of science fiction or fantasy?
- Was the film *marketed* as being science-fictional or fantastical?
- Do those that were involved in the production (cast and crew) consider the film to contain substantive elements of science-fiction or fantasy?

Unfortunately, while the latter two are objective, the first (and most important) of the measures is largely subjective, since we've never been able to come up with a **single clear-cut definition of what consists science fiction or fantasy.**

In short, I don't think we can come up with an objective system, nor do I think we should invest our energy in trying to do so.